# Is it possible to compile a VB6 class into a Linux shared object?

Tags: php, vb6

I have a legacy app written in PHP which runs on Windows IIS. I want to move the app to a Linux server, but there is a dependency in the app which uses a class written in VB through `ext-com_dotnet`. The class exists as `.dll` and is registered in Windows.

It's used like this:

```php
$thing = new COM('cls.className');
$result = $thing->doStuff();
```

I have the source code of the VB class, which has a `.cls` ending. Can I build/compile/convert/transform/* the class into a linux shared object (`.so`) file which I could include in my app as a custom php extension?

The class provides critial unique functionality for the app but has no dependencies itself and has only two public methods and a few internals.

Comment: Would probably be less of a hassle to recreate it in php or C?

Comment: In general I would agree but its a (probably customized) Rijndael implementation and I already tried to rebuild it directly in PHP but I was unable to get exactly the same results. It must be exactly compatible and I don't really understand the deep magic of VB6.

Comment: @Fildor - fyi, if the source file has a `.cls` extension, then this would be vb6, not vb.net.

Comment: @MarkL Yep, you're right. In that case, the proposed "upgrade" to .Net 6 is not that fruitful... I am beginning to fear OP has no other choice than a deep dive into VB6 :/

Comment: _"the app has no dependencies itself"_ is not true.  The app would be dependent on at least the vb runtime.  Of course that doesn't matter if the code is converted to another environment/language. But then the inherent dependencies in the new environment must be considered.

Comment: Is the Rijndael implementation "all self-implemented custom code" or does it use/is a warpper of the Windows CryptoAPI? If you're unsure, at least post portions of the VB6 code.

Comment: Maybe in the future as twinBASIC matures this will be possible; it is meant to be cross-platform and also VB6-compatible, as far asI understand it. https://www.twinbasic.com/

Comment: @MarkL I did not write that the app does not have dependencies itself, I meant the class.

Comment: @HelO'Ween Yes its completely custom code, as far as I can see it. There are no imports or any calls that look like a Windows API
I guess I have to live with IIS for this project :[